# Не работают запросы к API после сборки проекта

Tags: node.js, express, axios, nuxt.js

При тестировании в режиме разработки все ок, все axios запросы работают.
После сборки (npm run build && npm run start), приложение запускается и работает, но запросы к API нет.
В консоле ловлю _//localhost:3000/api/auth/generateKey пишет NOT FOUND 404

**Client:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
axios.get('api/auth/generateKey')
```

[image: network screen]

**Backend - app.js**

```
 const express = require('express')
 const app = express()
 const info = require('./routes/auth')
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  })
)
           
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, 
   OPTIONS')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, 
   Content-Type, Content-Length, x-access-token')
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.sendStatus(200)
    } else {
      next()
    }
  })

  app.use('/api/auth', auth({ express }))
  module.exports = app
```

**Backend - index.js**

```
const { loadNuxt, build } = require('nuxt')
const app = require('./app')
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000
const host = process.env.HOST || 'localhost'
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

async function start() {
  const nuxt = await loadNuxt(dev ? 'dev' : 'start')

  app.use(nuxt.render)
  if (dev) {
    build(nuxt)
  }

  app.listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log(`Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`)
  })
}
start()
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
...
axios: {
  baseURL: '/'
},
...
```

**Update:**

Даже если добавить обычный маршрут с выводом hello world, он также не отрабатывает, в режиме же разработки все ок.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
   res.status(200).send('Hello world!')
})
```

Comment: Прикрепите скрины с нетворка поданному axios, возможно даст больше информации.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить на хосте не режим разработки, а точно так же как это делаете в докере. Так работает?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, не понял вас.

Comment: Вы пишете "в режиме разработки все ок". Вы имеете ввиду, что при запуске на хосте используя точно те же команды для запуска все работает? Или речь о специальном режиме, для которого команды отличаются (типа watch или с дополнительными библиотеками и т.п.)?

Comment: @RomanKonoval, я имею ввиду npm run dev ("dev": "nodemon server/index.js --watch server")

Comment: В докере вы запускаете иначе, т.е. без watch. Начните с того, что проверьте чтоб у вас на хосте запускалось все так как вы пробуете в докере, т.е. `npm run start`. То что запускается `npm run dev` - ни о чем не говорит, у вас и без докера может быть сломана настройка проекта.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, спасибо, вы правы. Докер тут не причем, действительно при старте на хосте такое же поведение. Буду курить настройку

Comment: @Odyssey, попробуйте добавить путь до файла(API) в serverMiddleware, а в index.js убрать const app = require('./app'), --->https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware

Comment: @haswell, извините я новичок в разработке, не совсем понял как сделать, сделал как вы сказали но пока не выходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш app.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
...
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
   res.status(200).send('Hello world!')
})
module.exports = { path: '/api', handler: app }
```

Ваш nuxt.config.js, добавим промежуточное серверное по:

```
serverMiddleware: ['~/path/to/app.js']
```

Соответственно из index.js убираем const app = require('./app').
Теперь маршрут до api должен работать, localhost:3000/api/test ---> Hello world!

Comment: спасибо теперь все получилось)